# Obtaining a Month's Last Record Minus the Previous Month's Last Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My company uses telematics devices to capture data around miles driven by asset. What I'm looking to get is the last odometer reading of any given month - the last odometer reading of the previous month. I figured a window function may be best to obtain the MAX odometer value per day (see example below).

```
SELECT Date_FW, Vehicle_ID2_FW, Location_Code_FW, MAX(Odometer_Fw) OVER(PARTITION BY Vehicle_ID2_FW,Date_FW) as Max_Odo
FROM GPS_Trips_FW
```

Where I'm running into an issue is trying to conceptualize how to get the last entry, by date, for an asset in a given month (e.g. if there are entries for 6/28/18, 6/29/2018, and 6/30/2018 I only want the data for 6/30/2018 and filtering out any other information besides that). Furthermore, then subtracting any given month's MAX odometer - the previous month's MAX odometer (see examples below).

Sample Query Data:

```
|Date      |Asset #|Location   |Max Odo|
|6/30/2018 |1215   |Phoenix, AZ|17500  |
|6/29/2018 |1215   |Phoenix, AZ|17250  |
|6/28/2018 |1215   |Phoenix, AZ|17000  |
|…         |…      |…          |…      | 
|5/31/2018 |1215   |Phoenix, AZ|15000  |
|…         |…      |…          |…      |
|4/30/2018 |1215   |Phoenix, AZ|12000  |
```

Desired Query Results:

```
|Date      |Asset #|Location   |Odo Var|
|6/30/2018 |1215   |Phoenix, AZ|2500   |
|5/31/2018 |1215   |Phoenix, AZ|3000   |
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Thank you for the response! I added some sample data and desired results for what I'm trying to do. Let me know if it all makes sense.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Brian SQL Server 2012

Comment: @TabAlleman. . . This question is not similar with one which you have provided. Request you to open the question.

Comment: @TabAlleman, the "duplicate" you cited does not include logic for getting data from the previous month's record.

Comment: This is a two-part question, and both questions have been asked and answered many times before.   Although a single duplicate might not be found, the solutions to both parts of this question can be found on this site already, making this question of no particular value to future readers.   I still consider this question a duplicate that should be closed, but I will leave it to others to vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;With CTE_odo
As
(
Select 
    ore.Reading_Date
    , ore.Asset
    , ore.Location
    , ore.Reading
    , Row_Number() Over (Partition By ore.Asset, EOMonth(ore.Reading_Date) Order By ore.Reading_Date Desc) As RN
From dbo.Odo_Reading As ore
)

Select 
odo.Reading_Date
, odo.Asset
, odo.Location
, odo.Reading
, Lag(odo.Reading, 1) Over (Order By odo.Reading_Date) As Previous_Reading
, odo.Reading - Lag(odo.Reading, 1) Over (Order By odo.Reading_Date) As Month_Milage
From CTE_odo As odo
Where odo.RN = 1
-- this restricts the return to the last two months
And EOMonth(odo.Reading_Date) >= DateAdd(Month, -2, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Brian's approach, but it fixes some errors:

```
With r As (
      select r.* 
             row_Number() over (partition By r.Asset, EOMonth(r.Reading_Date) order by r.Reading_Date Desc) as seqnum
      from dbo.Odo_Reading As ore
     )
select reading_date, asset, location, reading,
       (reading - coalesce(prev_reading, 0)) as diff
from (select r.*,
             lag(r.reading, 1) Over (partition by asset order By r.Reading_Date) as Previous_Reading
      from r
      where r.seqnum = 1
     ) r
-- this restricts the return to the last two months
where EOMonth(r.Reading_Date) >= DateAdd(Month, -2, GetDate())
```

Comment: What errors did I miss when I tested the code that I posted?

Comment: @Brian . . . You missed the `partition by` and a default value for the lag.  On the other hand, like the use of `eomonth()`.

Comment: I thought the `partition by` in the CTE covered it, and I like having a `NULL` on `Lead` and `Lag` as sentinel values.  And yea, I'm a big fan of `EOMonth` - I use it a lot.